# Disable and Enable cells based on another cell in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The first column of my spreadsheet has dropdown lists in each cell with the options "yes" and "no".

If "yes" is selected, I want to enable the cell in the same row, next column with another dropdown list with options "red" and "blue". If "no" is selected, then the next cell should remain disabled.

So far I have tried the data validation menu with custom formula is set to `=if(B2="Yes", "red", "blue")` in cell B3, but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check out youtube video's from Jason Jurotich here's a [link](https://youtu.be/rW9T4XZy-7U) to one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with onEdit and script like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var col=e.range.getColumn()
  var ro=e.range.getRow()
  var nota=e.range.getA1Notation()
  if(col==1){
  var val=e.range.getValue()
  if(val=="No"){
    s.getRange(ro,2,1,1).setDataValidation(null)
   }
      else{
      s.getRange(ro,2,1,1).clearContent()      
      var cell = s.getRange(ro,2,1,1);
      var rule =  
SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Red', 'Blue']).build();
 cell.setDataValidation(rule);
      }}}
```

Here is a share example. Copy and try it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wHA1Rz9U9dr4n8DntLvZWPe4izck7xgi3ygUpx-uNmo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am getting this error with this script: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 4, file "Code")

Comment: Sounds like you need to approve the script in the script editor. If not approved, the event (e) is blank and the script will fail.